# How to install AIRBAG

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, installation, collision-detection

I was recently directed towards a blog-post containing a collisiondetectionkit called airbag: http://cote.cc/projects/airbag . How would I install this?
It comes with 4 folders, called `_MACOSX, demos, doc,` and `src`. The doc contains html files, demos are demos, and i'm not on a mac, so I assume the `src` folder actually has what i need. It comes with folders and in each folder there is a `.DS_Store` file. In order, the folders go: `src>cc>cote>airbag>` and then three `.as` files called: `AirBag.as AirBagEvent.as` and `Collision.as`. This is all I can understand from it, so all help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is the .as files. Copy the content of src folder and paste it to your project's folder. That's it.

Comment: what do you mean by "project folder", like: Just the folder where my .fla files are?

Comment: If you have only a fla file, then yes.

Comment: Ok, although now I get an error: 1114: The public attribute can only be used inside a package. I got the code from: http://cote.cc/projects/airbag (The second and third boxes under "code examples")

Comment: @user2789610 That's another problem you are having there. You are *probably* declaring a public method/variable in your timeline script. You cannot do that, it must be inside of a class (or well, the class... => inside of a package :) ).

Comment: So I can put all the function n' such in a class? But would I need to write anything in the code that involves a package?

Comment: I recommend you to go to read a tutorial about AS3 basics because you are really confused how the stuff works in Flash. You can put your code into the frames in Flash IDE or create classes (objects) and use those. You do not need to use classes, but you can use the 'public' keyword only in a class, not in a timeline script.